# Main process for two sub_main process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am working on the integration of two different framework, say Main_process1.py and Main_process2.py. Consider, Main_process1.py have a main() and Main_process2.py have another main().

So, i have changed the main() as main1() and main2() respectively for Main_process1.py and Main_process2.py and created a new file like overall_Main.py.

The new file overall_Main.py will have two process, one starting main1() in Main_process1.py and main2() in  Main_process2.py.

Basically, what's required is, an overall main process has to be created for two different main processes. Please give some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This is, like, the very basics of Python Multiprocessing:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from Main_process1 import main1
from Main_process2 import main2

if __name__ == '__main__':
  p1 = Process(target=main1, args=(list your args for main1 here,))
  p2 = Process(target=main2, args=(list your args for main2 here,))
  p1.start()
  p2.start()

#your other main code

p1.join()
p2.join()
```